# How do I count distinct timestamps for each day in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some sql below that returns

[image: Output]

```
select
  distinct(file_modified_datetime),
  count(distinct(date_trunc('day',file_modified_datetime)))
from inv_by_wh_and_lot
group by file_modified_datetime
```

I'm looking to show a subtotal of this count for each day whereby 2021-06-23 would return 2

Comment: maybe this? `select
  file_modified_datetime::date,
  count(distinct(date_trunc('day',file_modified_datetime)))
from inv_by_wh_and_lot
group by file_modified_datetime::date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the timestamp to date and group by it:

```
SELECT f::date,sum(c) FROM (
  SELECT file_modified_datetime,
     count(distinct file_modified_datetime) FROM t
  GROUP BY file_modified_datetime) j (f,c)
GROUP BY f::date;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=65764f69100f737891d44ab8efb5d5ac)

```
WITH t (file_modified_datetime) AS (
  VALUES ('2021-06-01 11:24:55'::timestamp),
         ('2021-06-01 11:24:55'::timestamp),
         ('2021-06-01 18:26:51'::timestamp),
         ('2021-06-05 19:08:12'::timestamp)
)
SELECT f::date,sum(c) FROM (
  SELECT file_modified_datetime,
     count(distinct file_modified_datetime) FROM t
  GROUP BY file_modified_datetime) j (f,c)
GROUP BY f::date;

     f      | sum 
------------+-----
 2021-06-05 |   1
 2021-06-01 |   2
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks Jim - let me expand some as this still isn't returning as expected. I have incoming files where I add a column with a timestamp. Sometimes these files come in once or twice a day. I'm looking to see how many days have 1 or more incoming files. When casting the ::date it doesn't reflect the right count; still 1 for 2021-06-23. When I remove the ::date from the groupby it returns two instances of 2021-06-23 with count of 1. Getting closer!

Comment: @Neil.Corbin Even if you count like this it returns only 1?? `SELECT
  file_modified_datetime::date,
  count(file_modified_datetime)
FROM inv_by_wh_and_lot
GROUP BY file_modified_datetime::date`

Comment: that counts the # of records within each file and given the date casting on the group by it will total the records for that day which is accurate

Comment: @Neil.Corbin so it does solve your problem? :-D

Comment: not quite but close - attempting to count the number of files for a certain day as opposed to the number of records for a day.

Comment: @Neil.Corbin could you provide some sample data (as text, not images), preferably in a fiddle. I can't see any information about the file. Is it a new column?

Comment: yes - when each file comes in I place a timestamp on the records - try this: [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d60517a1a965a33e6f89e5fe518f90d9)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234174/discussion-between-jim-jones-and-neil-corbin).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, casting the timestamp to date in the group by

```
select
  file_modified_datetime::date,
  count(*)
from inv_by_wh_and_lot
group by file_modified_datetime::date
```

Comment: Thanks Juan - it seems casting a date gives the appearance of one incoming file instead of 2 for 2021-06-23. When I remove the ::date from the groupby it returns two instances of 2021-06-23 with count of 1 so almost there.